# Regex match for key in jinja2 selectattr()

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given the data:

```
"serverName", [
    serverData: [
          { 
            "internal_ip": "10.1.1.100",
            "external_ip": "172.16.1.10",
            "name": "dns-1"
      },
    ],
]
```

This extracts the `name` value `dns-1` when the `internal_ip` matches the `equalto`. So far, so good.

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{  mydict | selectattr('internal_ip', 'equalto', '10.1.1.100') |  
   map(attribute='name') | list  }}"
```

In the real problem, I *do not* know which type of *_ip will the ip address I'm searching for will reside. It could be under `internal_ip`, it could be under `external_ip` and for all I know, there could be even more options, the only thing that will always be there - is the actual IP address I'm searching for: '10.1.1.100`.

So I need to regex match like so:

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{  mydict | selectattr('^.*$', 'equalto', '10.1.1.100') |  
   map(attribute='name') | list  }}"
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it seems to be one of the ways out of this jam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mylist:
      - {internal_ip: 10.1.1.101, external_ip: 172.16.1.10, name: dns-1}
      - {internal_ip: 10.1.1.102, external_ip: 172.16.1.10, name: dns-2}
      - {internal_ip: 10.1.1.103, external_ip: 172.16.1.10, name: dns-3}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        sel: "{{ sel|default([]) + [item.name] }}"
      loop: "{{ mylist }}"
      when: sel_ip|default('') in item.values()|list
    - debug:
        var: sel
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e sel_ip=172.16.1.10
  ...
  sel:
  - dns-1
  - dns-2
  - dns-3
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e sel_ip=10.1.1.103
  ...
  sel:
  - dns-3
```

Comment: This indeed works. I've edited my original json data as it is more complex than original. I must iterate while not hard coding servername. I do feel a jinja2 loop would be a great solution is, but I'm experiencing an odd behavior (it turns lists to strings eventhought I'm using `|from_json`. I may just open another question with that one.

Comment: Yes. Open a new question. JFYI, a string in YAML is de facto a list of characters (this would cause a reverse problem of turning strings into lists).

Comment: @G_G while opening a new question is the good path, giving credit to the answer you received is also a good idea. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε did you mean to mark the answer as "accepted" ?

Comment: @G_G you are the only one choosing if the answer should be accepted or not. This said I understood from your first comment that the answer did help you. If this is the case, then even without accepting the answer, I would say it, at least, deserves an upvote. (As the tooltip on the upvote states it *This answer is useful*).